# how to upload image,recording file,thumbnail through HttpUrlConnection POST method One request in android

Tags: android, http, post

i want to send thumb_nail,recording-file,wifi scan result on server through Httpurlconnection one request in android

Comment: check out here.http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/ and here. https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-to-server-using-php-mysql/

Comment: @Chandan Baba pu your code what you have tried?

Comment: @DaminiMehra code is below  in comment

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DataUpload extends IntentService {
    StringBuilder sbList;
    String stringconvert;
   File fileRoomRecord;
    File fileWifiUpload;
    public DataUpload() {
        super("DataUpload");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        //get downfile and upload

        if (intent.getBooleanExtra("WIFI", false)) {
    enter code here
            while (Values.getRoomRecord(getApplicationContext()) >= Values.getRoomRecordUpload(getApplicationContext())) {
                if (Values.getRoomRecord(getApplicationContext()) == Values.getRoomRecordUpload(getApplicationContext()) && Values.isRecorderStarted(getApplicationContext()))
                    break;
                 fileRoomRecord = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "AudioRoom" + File.separator + "recording" + Values.getRoomRecordUpload(getApplicationContext()) + "_" + Values.getUid(getApplicationContext()) + ".3gpp");
                Log.i("Test", "FILE FOUND " + fileRoomRecord.exists());
                Values.setWifiCount(Values.getWifiCount(getApplicationContext()) + 1, getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStreamGps = new FileOutputStream(fileRoomRecord);
                    fileOutputStreamGps.write((" WIFI available " + fileRoomRecord + "\n Time : " + Values.Date(System.currentTimeMillis())).getBytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (fileRoomRecord.exists()) {
                    boolean uploaded = false;
                    try {
                        uploaded = upload(fileRoomRecord);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (uploaded) {
                        try {
                            boolean a = fileRoomRecord.getCanonicalFile().delete();
                            Log.i("Test", "Room Record : " + a);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Values.setRoomRecordUpload(Values.getRoomRecordUpload(getApplicationContext()) + 1, getApplicationContext());
                    } else break;
                } else break;
            }

            while (Values.getGpsCount(getApplicationContext()) >= Values.getGpsCountUpload(getApplicationContext())) {
                File fileGpsUpload = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Gps" + File.separator + "gps" + Values.getGpsCountUpload(getApplicationContext()) + "_" + Values.getUid(getApplicationContext()) + ".txt");
                File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                sbList = new StringBuilder();
                lookForFilesAndDirectories(root);
                File fileEXT = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Storage" + File.separator + "external" + Values.getExternalCount(getApplicationContext()) + "_" + Values.getUid(getApplicationContext()) + ".txt");
                Log.d("file", fileEXT.toString());
                try {
                    FileOutputStream fosEXT = new FileOutputStream(fileEXT);
                    fosEXT.write(sbList.toString().getBytes());
                    Values.setExternalCount(Values.getExternalCount(getApplicationContext()) + 1, getApplicationContext());

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (fileEXT.exists()) {
                    boolean uploaded = false;
                    try {
                        uploaded = upload(fileEXT);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (uploaded) {
                        try {
                            boolean a = fileEXT.getCanonicalFile().delete();
                            Log.i("Test", "GPS Record : " + a);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Values.setGpsCountUpload(Values.getGpsCountUpload(getApplicationContext()) + 1, getApplicationContext());
                    } else break;
                } else break;
            }
        }

        while (Values.getWifiCount(getApplicationContext()) >= Values.getWifiCountUpload(getApplicationContext())) {
            File fileWifiUpload = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Wifi" + File.separator + "wifiScan" + Values.getWifiCountUpload(getApplicationContext()) + "_" + Values.getUid(getApplicationContext()) + ".txt");
            if (fileWifiUpload.exists()) {
                boolean uploaded = false;
                try {
                    uploaded = upload(fileWifiUpload);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (uploaded) {
                    try {
                        boolean a = fileWifiUpload.getCanonicalFile().delete();
                        Log.i("xxxx", "Wifi Record : " + a);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Values.setWifiCountUpload(Values.getWifiCountUpload(getApplicationContext()) + 1, getApplicationContext());
                } else break;
            } else break;
        }

        while (Values.getExternalCount(getApplicationContext()) >= Values.getExternalCountUpload(getApplicationContext())) {
             fileWifiUpload = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Wifi" + File.separator + "wifiScan" + Values.getWifiCountUpload(getApplicationContext()) + "_" + Values.getUid(getApplicationContext()) + ".txt");
            if (fileWifiUpload.exists()) {
                boolean uploaded = false;
                try {
                    uploaded = upload(fileWifiUpload);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (uploaded) {
                    try {
                        boolean a = fileWifiUpload.getCanonicalFile().delete();
                        Log.i("xxxx", "Wifi Record : " + a);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Values.setExternalCountUpload(Values.getExternalCountUpload(getApplicationContext()) + 1, getApplicationContext());
                } else break;
            } else break;
        }

        while (Values.getThumbCount(getApplicationContext()) >= Values.getThumbCountUpload(getApplicationContext())) {
            File fileThumbUpload = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Thumb" + File.separator + "thumb" + Values.getThumbCountUpload(getApplicationContext()) + "_" + Values.getUid(getApplicationContext()) + ".png");
            if (fileThumbUpload.exists()) {
                boolean uploaded = false;
                try {
                    uploaded = upload(fileThumbUpload);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (uploaded) {
                    try {
                        boolean a = fileThumbUpload.getCanonicalFile().delete();
                        Log.i("xxxx", "Wifi Record : " + a);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Values.setThumbCountUpload(Values.getThumbCountUpload(getApplicationContext()) + 1, getApplicationContext());
                } else break;
            } else break;
        }
    }

    public void lookForFilesAndDirectories(File file) {
        File[] fileArray = file.listFiles();
        if (fileArray != null) {
            for (File fileList : fileArray) {
                if (fileList.isDirectory()) {
                    lookForFilesAndDirectories(fileList);
                } else {
                    sbList.append(fileList.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
        public boolean upload(File fileupload) throws IOException {
            TelephonyManager tm1 =(TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            final String imei =tm1.getDeviceId();

            //   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                URL url = new URL("https://rootserver1.com/getbindata.aspx");
                Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                params.put("UID",imei);
                params.put("DATA",fileWifiUpload);
                params.put("FNAME","wifi.txt");


                StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
                for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
                    if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
                    postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                    postData.append('=');
                    postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
                }
                byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

                Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

                for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
                    System.out.print((char)c);
            return Boolean.parseBoolean(null);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to upload an audio file to the server .

```
 String file = intent.getStringExtra("audioFile");
                filePath = file;
                String type = intent.getStringExtra("type");
                Log.e("", "filepath" + file);
                HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                DataOutputStream dos = null;

                String lineEnd = "\r\n";
                String twoHyphens = "--";
                DataInputStream inStream = null;
                String boundary = "*****";
                //  String[] parts = file.split("/");


                int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
                byte[] buffer;

                int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

                File sourceFile = new File(file);
                Log.e("File Path Aysnc", sourceFile + "");
                if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
                    Log.e("Not a File", sourceFile + "");
//                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    return;
                } else {
                    try {

                        Log.e("Is a File", sourceFile + "");
                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                        URL url = new URL("http://localhost/audio.php");

                        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                        conn.setDoInput(true);

                        conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                        conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

                        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);


                        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());


                        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + file + "\"" + lineEnd);

                        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                        bytesAvailable = fis.available();
                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                        bytesRead = fis.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                        while (bytesRead > 0)

                        {

                            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                            bytesAvailable = fis.available();
                            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);

                            bytesRead = fis.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);


                        }

                        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
                        // close streams
                        Log.e("Debug", "File is written");
                        fis.close();
                        dos.flush();
                        dos.close();


                    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
                    }

                    try {

                        inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());


                        while ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {


                            Log.e("Debug", "Server Response " + str);
                            if (str.equals("success") && type.equals("yes")) {
                                deleteFiles();
                                Log.e(str + "", "");
                                builder.setContentText("Upload Complete");
                                builder.setProgress(0,0,false);
                                notificationManager.notify(1,builder.build());

                                notificationManager.cancelAll();



                            }
                            if (str.equals("success") && type.equals("no")) {
                                Log.e(str + "", "");
                                builder.setContentText("Upload Complete");
                                builder.setProgress(0,0,false);
                                notificationManager.notify(1,builder.build());
                                notificationManager.cancelAll();

                                //   deleteFiles();
                                   deleteRecords();

                            }
                        }


                        inStream.close();

                    } catch (IOException ioex) {
                        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
                    }


                }
```

This is php file code(name it audio.php)

```
<?php

    $file_path = "uploads/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path) ){
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

Make a local server using xampp and put this file php file in htdocs folder and also create a folder names uploads inside htdocs folder.